# How to Handle a Column of string of integers to apply a mathematical operation on it

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-cleaning, feature-selection

[image]

I have a Column with data as a String. I want to replace all these values with their actual ratios i.e
'6.2/5.1' to 1.2156 i.e their actual value after division as I cannot use the original values directly in my model. I tried splitting the strings using the strip function but I don't understand how to replace it with values at the correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but i think you can use `eval` and `apply` to get the job done.

```
df['DELTA-T(L/R)'].apply(eval)
```

**UPDATE**:
I tried and it works..
Here is the sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ratio': ['1.2/.25', '1/2',  '2/3']})
df
     ratio
0  1.2/.25
1      1/2
2      2/3
df['ratio'].apply(eval)
0    4.800000
1    0.500000
2    0.666667
Name: ratio, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method that does what you want to accomplish, such as:

```
def convert_to_float(s):
  nums = s.split("/")
  return float(nums[0]) / float(nums[1])

s = '6.2/5.1'
convert_to_float(s)
>  1.215686274509804
```

Then you can use the *apply* method from pandas as such:

```
df['DELTA-T(L/R)'].apply(lambda x: convert_to_float(x))
```

### EDIT:

ThePyGuy solution is more concise and should be used over mine.